# SQL: Optimize query/ Reduce the size of the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT p.Distributor,
       SUM(r.SalesVolume)                                                                                                          AS Sales,
       CAST(( ( CAST(SUM(r.SalesVolume) AS DECIMAL(14, 4)) / (SELECT SUM(r.SalesVolume)
                                                              FROM   RawData r
                                                                     INNER JOIN Product p
                                                                             ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
                                                              WHERE  p.Distributor IN( 'TF1', 'WARNER', 'GAUMONT', 'PATHE',
                                                                                       'STUDIOCANAL', 'M6SND', 'FRANCETV' )
                                                                     AND p.VODEST IN ( 'EST' )
                                                                     AND p.ContentFlavor IN ( 'HD' )) ) * 100 ) AS DECIMAL(20, 2)) AS MarketSharesVolume
FROM   RawData r
       INNER JOIN Product p
               ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE  p.Distributor IN ( 'TF1', 'WARNER', 'GAUMONT', 'PATHE',
                          'STUDIOCANAL', 'M6SND', 'FRANCETV' )
       AND p.VODEST IN ( 'EST' )
       AND p.ContentFlavor IN ( 'HD' )
GROUP  BY p.Distributor;
```

The above query doesnt look beautiful for sure. Basically if you notice the `WHERE` conditions in the sub query and the main query are similar. Is there a way I can combine them to reduce the size of this query. Also are there any other place where I could probably try and reduce the size of this query?
Looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUM ... OVER()` on the `SUM` to count up the grand total.

```
SELECT p.Distributor,
       SUM(r.SalesVolume)                                                                          AS Sales,
       CAST(( ( CAST(SUM(r.SalesVolume) AS DECIMAL(14, 4)) / SUM(SUM(r.SalesVolume))
                                                               OVER() ) * 100 ) AS DECIMAL(20, 2)) AS MarketSharesVolume
FROM   RawData r
       INNER JOIN Product p
               ON r.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE  p.Distributor IN ( 'TF1', 'WARNER', 'GAUMONT', 'PATHE',
                          'STUDIOCANAL', 'M6SND', 'FRANCETV' )
       AND p.VODEST IN ( 'EST' )
       AND p.ContentFlavor IN ( 'HD' )
GROUP  BY p.Distributor;
```

Comment: That worked perfect, thank you. However I was wondering how does that function work? Maybe you could explain it in simple terms if possible.

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . The `cast()`s are pretty useless because SQL Server follows its own rules for the scale and precision of a ratio.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Just copied from the OP.

Comment: @TauseefHussain - http://www.bidn.com/blogs/KathiKellenberger/sql-server/4397/what-is-a-window-aggregate-function